# PuTTY can access serial port as /dev/ttyUSB0, but not as named udev device

Tags: udev, putty, serial-port

I have multiple USB-to-serial converters. I need to access one of them in particular. I'm using a udev rule to give it a special name. I have rebooted since I last modified it.

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea60", NAME="serial", MODE="0666"
```

That vendor/product combination is unique among all of my usb devices.

```
$ ls -l /dev/serial
crw-rw-rw-. 1 root root 189, 133 Feb  8 23:57 /dev/serial
$ ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw----. 1 root dialout 188, 0 Feb  8 23:58 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I'm using PuTTY to read them, and it works on `/dev/ttyUSB0`, but not on `/dev/serial` . The error still appears when I am running PuTTY as root.

[image: The error message I receive]

```
Unable to open connection to :
Unable to configure serial port
```

In case it matters, I'm running CentOS 6.

```
uname -a
Linux xxxxxx 2.6.32-279.22.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Feb 6 03:10:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

## EDIT: WORKING

The following udev rule was what finally worked:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea60", SYMLINK+="COM1", MODE="0666"
```

Note that `SUBSYSTEM` is tty, not usb, `NAME` has been changed to `SYMLINK+`, and serial has been changed to COM1 (to not interfere with /dev/serial, as a commenter pointed out.)

Thanks for your help, guys!

Comment: Does the /dev/serial device get created? PuTTY is a userland application, it should just use whatever devices are available.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I posted an `ls -l` of /dev/serial. Is there some other command I should run to determine whether it got created?

Comment: Your /dev/serial is a different device than /dev/ttyUSB0... My udev man page here tells me that NAME is applicable only to network interfaces, other devices only get symlinks made to them (with the SYMLINK key). Perhaps you should change NAME for SYMLINK

Comment: I initially had it as SYMLINK+="serial", but that didn't work so I changed it.

Comment: putty on linux?

Comment: @Keith [Yep.](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=putty)

Comment: @NickODell Interesting. But I don't see the point.

Comment: @Keith Of being able to read from your serial ports?

Comment: @NickODell No, I mean of running a port of putty when there already exists more traditional tools for that, such as minicom or kermit. I prefer kermit. These both run in terminal window of your choice.

Comment: @Keith Couldn't get minicom to work. PuTTY worked without hassle. I really don't care how 'traditional' the tools I use are, as long as they work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want your rule to pay attention to the `tty` subsystem, not the `usb` one.

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea60", SYMLINK+="serial"
```

A USB device generates several udev events when you plug it in as the kernel recognizes more things about it.  Since it's a USB device, it first engages the `usb` subsystem, which I think will create a raw USB device, which PuTTY can't use.  A few steps later it will load the device's specific driver, and since this is a serial device, it will engage the `tty` subsystem, which creates a device file that PuTTY *can* use.

This rule will create a symlink to whichever `/dev/ttyUSB*` happens to be assigned to your device.  Tested successfully with PuTTY on my own serial dongle.

Incidentally, for diagnostics I sometimes run the following rule, to get an idea of what the udev scripts are seeing:

```
RUN+="/home/me/bin/udev-diag .$kernel .$number .$devpath .$id .$parent .$root .$tempnode"
```

where `udev-diag` is essentially:

```
env >>/tmp/udev-events
echo "$@" >>/tmp/udev-events
```

For more general use, the `udevmonitor` program is also handy.

Comment: On a Debian-based system, the existing udev rules may already create a `/dev/serial/*` tree, which can conflict with this one.  You can avoid this by choosing a different name for the symlink.  I'm not sure if this is an issue on a CentOS system.

Comment: Jander, you are correct. As soon as I rebooted with the new rule, I found that /dev/serial contained a directory, so I was stomping over that with my symlink.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jander's rule, I *was* able to access my USB serial adapter... but *only* if running PuTTY as root.

Modifying the rule to specify different permissions allowed me to access it by any user.

I.E.

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea60", MODE="0666", SYMLINK+="serial"
```

Comment: I'm using MODE 666 too. See the question.

Answer (score 0):

The following udev rule was what finally worked:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea60", SYMLINK+="COM1", MODE="0666"
```

Note that `SUBSYSTEM` is tty, not usb, `NAME` has been changed to `SYMLINK+`, and serial has been changed to COM1 (to not interfere with /dev/serial, as a commenter pointed out.)

Comment: In the future, please just post an answer and improve it when necessary. Leaving old irrelevant stuff around in everybody face is just a time waster. If we need to, we can use the edit history to see what changed.

Comment: Im so sorry. 
I didn't update it. Thanks Anthon.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I never posted an answer to this, even after I got this working.

The following udev rule was what finally worked:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea60", SYMLINK+="COM1", MODE="0666"
```

Note that `SUBSYSTEM` is tty, not usb, `NAME` has been changed to `SYMLINK+`, and serial has been changed to COM1 (to not interfere with /dev/serial, as a commenter pointed out.)

Thanks for your help, guys!

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the device is group-writable, by the group dialout.

```
$ ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
**crw-rw----** 1 root **dialout** 188, 0 Feb  8 23:58 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

To fix this permissions issue, add yourself to the dialout group:

```
$ sudo adduser <username> dialout
```

Then restart the session

Comment: You can edit your posts.

Comment: Welcome to Unix.stackexchange! I recommend you [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).