# How to match a ttyUSBX device to a usb serial device

Tags: linux, usb

option driver correctly matched USB ID and loads driver for this device. For example

```
# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 19d2:0031 ONDA Communication S.p.A. ZTE MF636
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 12d1:14ac Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
```

It also creates ttyUSBX devices for managing the hardware

```
crw-rw---- 1 root uucp 188, 0 Jul  4 13:48 /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw---- 1 root uucp 188, 1 Jul  4 13:49 /dev/ttyUSB1
crw-rw---- 1 root uucp 188, 2 Jul  4 13:35 /dev/ttyUSB2
crw-rw---- 1 root uucp 188, 3 Jul  4 13:37 /dev/ttyUSB3
crw-rw---- 1 root uucp 188, 4 Jul  4 13:37 /dev/ttyUSB4
crw-rw---- 1 root uucp 188, 5 Jul  4 13:37 /dev/ttyUSB5
crw-rw---- 1 root uucp 188, 6 Jul  4 13:37 /dev/ttyUSB6
crw-rw---- 1 root uucp 188, 7 Jul  4 13:37 /dev/ttyUSB7
```

However, I have more then one usb serial devices and I want to know which ttyUSB is for which USBID. Ex. /dev/ttyUSB1 -> 19d2:0031

Do you know any point where I can get this information?

Comment: If you know details like vendor/product, then [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144029/command-to-determine-ports-of-a-device-like-dev-ttyusb0) is great

Comment: A HowTo about this problem can be found under https://www.railcontrol.org/index.php/en/dokumentation-en/config-rs232-usb-en

Answer (score 20):

You can try to see if your device(s) are registered under /dev/serial/by-id/

> ls -l /dev/serial/by-id

These names should be consistent and will point (symlink) to the correct ttyUSBx

Comment: Can you add some clarifications, examples, etc. Oneline answer do not count as good in SE

Comment: @RomeoNinov Ok, I added some clarification as you requested. This is not exactly more difficult than just looking into another directory, so I can't see how making the answer more elaborate than it is will improve anything. Sorry about that.

Comment: I have two identical adapters (two Arduinos) connected to a Raspberry Pi. `ls -l /dev/serial/by-id` only returns one adapter `../../ttyUSB1`, while `ls -l /sys/bus/usb-serial/devices` shows me both. So I don't think that this is a good answer.

Answer (score 19):

Have a look at the sysfs filesystem. An example for my USB serial:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 016: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
$ ls -l /sys/bus/usb-serial/devices
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jul  4 17:37 ttyUSB0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/ttyUSB0
$ $ grep PRODUCT= /sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/ttyUSB0/../uevent
PRODUCT=67b/2303/300
```

As you can see, `ttyUSB0` maps to `067b:2303` on my computer. An other locations worth exploring are `/sys/class/tty/`. Pay attention to symlinks.

Comment: did you do anything to make it list also the PRODUCT ?

Comment: @IgorStoppa, Try to `cat` the `uevent` file from the result of `find /sys -name ttyACM0`, for example. Substitute your serial device's node name.

Answer (score 7):

I had a [similar problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64266/putty-can-access-serial-port-as-dev-ttyusb0-but-not-as-named-udev-device).

Write this to /etc/udev/rules.d/50-usb.rules

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="19d2", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0031", SYMLINK+="ONDA"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="14ac", SYMLINK+="HUAWEI"
```

to the end. Reboot.

Now you can use `/dev/ONDA` to get to your ONDA device.

If you want non-root users to be able to use these, then add

```
, MODE="0666"
```

to the end of each line.

Comment: I did this and checked the files where they link to. the product I have has multiple interfaces, like solid disk, usb serial. While I expected the linkage to /dev/ttyACM0 but it was to /dev/sda. any way to define in rules file which device type the rule should apply? I wrote the rules in /etc/udev/rules.d/99-ftdi.rules

Comment: ok found it: added SUBSYSTEM=="tty" to the rule parameters. this value can be found in the output of  `udevadm info --name=/dev/ttyACM0`

Answer (score 5):

I would use udev and write some rules which create symlinks for the devices.

To get enough information to distinguish the devices try something like this for all devices:

```
$ udevadm info --query all --name /dev/ttyUSB0 --attribute-walk
```

Answer (score 1):

The following commands will give me list of ttyUSB device names that are associated with 19d2:0016 (which is the "modem mode" id of a ZTE MF831 LTE stick, yours may differ.):

```
    for i in $(find -L /sys/bus/usb/devices/ -maxdepth 2 -name "ttyUSB*"); do
        egrep -i "v19d2p0016(.*)in02" $i/../modalias >/dev/null && echo "/dev/${i##*/}"
    done
```

This will loop through a list of files with filename ttyUSB*, including symlinks, in /sys/bus/usb/devices. Within the results we will search for a file named modalias and look for a string containing the vendor id "v" "19d2" and product id "p" 0016. If the output matches, we will echo a string prefixed with "/dev/" in front of the USB? name.
Afaik the first or the usually the last (highest number) is the modem port for ZTE devices. You can echo the results to a file in /tmp/ and head -n1 or tail -n1 the lines accordingly.
If you have hubs, you may probably need to increase maxdepth.

This isn't the most elegant way, but it will work on almost any Linux variant.