# command to determine ports of a device (like /dev/ttyUSB0)

Tags: usb, serial-port, dmesg

I have a question regarding the ports in Linux. If I connect my device via USB and want to check its port I can't do it using the command lsusb, which only specifies bus number and device number on this bus:

```
[ziga@Ziga-PC ~]$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
```

**Is there a command that tells me the port the device is connected to directly?** Only way to do this until now was to disconect and reconnect and using the command:

```
[ziga@Ziga-PC ~]$ dmesg | grep tty
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    0.929510] 00:09: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[    4.378109] systemd[1]: Starting system-getty.slice.
[    4.378543] systemd[1]: Created slice system-getty.slice.
[    8.786474] usb 3-4.4: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

In the last line it can be seen that my device is connected to **/dev/ttyUSB0**.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to associate a device in `/dev` with an entry in `lsusb`? Or do you want to list all devices in `/dev` that are derived from a physical USB device? Or are you just wanting `ls /dev/ttyUSB*`?

Comment: I just need a command which will give me port of a device and will not push me to disconnect and reconnect my devices. `ls /dev/ttyUSB*` will only list maybee 10 ports but from this list I cannot tell which one is for my device.

Comment: I found this to be helpful. lsusb -v

Comment: I use this Python 3 script all the time, it works perfectly well on Linux, macOS and Raspberry Pi OS: https://gist.github.com/NicHub/d86d34f2292da017ac20ca1e6a7cb76d

Answer (score 148, accepted):

I'm not quite certain what you're asking. You mention 'port' several times, but then in your example, you say the answer is `/dev/ttyUSB0`, which is a device dev path, not a port. So this answer is about finding the dev path for each device.

Below is a quick and dirty script which walks through devices in `/sys` looking for USB devices with a `ID_SERIAL` attribute. Typically only real USB devices will have this attribute, and so we can filter with it. If we don't, you'll see a lot of things in the list that aren't physical devices.

```
#!/bin/bash

for sysdevpath in $(find /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/ -name dev); do
    (
        syspath="${sysdevpath%/dev}"
        devname="$(udevadm info -q name -p $syspath)"
        [[ "$devname" == "bus/"* ]] && exit
        eval "$(udevadm info -q property --export -p $syspath)"
        [[ -z "$ID_SERIAL" ]] && exit
        echo "/dev/$devname - $ID_SERIAL"
    )
done
```

On my system, this results in the following:

```
/dev/ttyACM0 - LG_Electronics_Inc._LGE_Android_Phone_VS930_4G-991c470
/dev/sdb - Lexar_USB_Flash_Drive_AA26MYU15PJ5QFCL-0:0
/dev/sdb1 - Lexar_USB_Flash_Drive_AA26MYU15PJ5QFCL-0:0
/dev/input/event5 - Logitech_USB_Receiver
/dev/input/mouse1 - Logitech_USB_Receiver
/dev/input/event2 - Razer_Razer_Diamondback_3G
/dev/input/mouse0 - Razer_Razer_Diamondback_3G
/dev/input/event3 - Logitech_HID_compliant_keyboard
/dev/input/event4 - Logitech_HID_compliant_keyboard
```

---

#### Explanation:

```
find /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/ -name dev
```

Devices which show up in `/dev` have a `dev` file in their `/sys` directory. So we search for directories matching this criteria.

```
syspath="${sysdevpath%/dev}"
```

We want the directory path, so we strip off `/dev`.

```
devname="$(udevadm info -q name -p $syspath)"
```

This gives us the path in `/dev` that corresponds to this `/sys` device.

```
[[ "$devname" == "bus/"* ]] && exit
```

This filters out things which aren't actual devices. Otherwise you'll get things like USB controllers & hubs. The `exit` exits the subshell, which flows to the next iteration of the loop.

```
eval "$(udevadm info -q property --export -p $syspath)"
```

The `udevadm info -q property --export` command lists all the device properties in a format that can be parsed by the shell into variables. So we simply call `eval` on this. This is also the reason why we wrap the code in the parenthesis, so that we use a subshell, and the variables get wiped on each loop.

```
[[ -z "$ID_SERIAL" ]] && exit
```

More filtering of things that aren't actual devices.

```
echo "/dev/$devname - $ID_SERIAL"
```

I hope you know what this line does :-)

Comment: Thank you. I will learn a lot from your anwser and now I see that terms werent completely clear to me. Is there any shorter way? Maybee a command already integrated in the Linux itself?

Comment: Nope. If there was a pre-existing command, I would happily recommend it.

Comment: Suggest to change /bin/bash to /bin/sh and remove the ( ) for max compatibility

Comment: Doesn't work on Ubuntu 19.10 without removing the ()

Comment: @albfan Do the `()` not create a necessary subshell so that variables exported from the previous loop iterations do not carry over to the next? I assumed that was the purpose.

Comment: @Walf Yes, that is the purpose. The `eval` creates unknown variables that differ per device. Without `()`, when it checks `$ID_SERIAL`, it could be from a previous device.

Comment: Great script! Should come as a standard Linux command.

Comment: This should be added as a standard command in Linux.

Answer (score 24):

You can use this command to explore your device if connected to `usb0`:

```
udevadm info -a -p  $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/ttyUSB0)
```

Answer (score 15):

Assuming that you know what the device you plugged in is, in 14.04 Ubuntu, at least, there is the command `usb-devices` that you can look through and find the information:

```
$ usb-devices

T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 3
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=04.04
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.4.0-131-generic ehci_hcd
S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:1a.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
```

And the first line lists bus and port, as well as the device number that `lsusb` gives.

Comment: this does not show the `/dev/*` path

Comment: To be fair, as the top answer notes, the question isn't clear on whether it's asking for "how do I derive the port" vs "how do I get the exact path?".

Comment: Is there a way to derive the `/dev/...` name from this information?

Answer (score 5):

I found @phemmer's accepted answer regularly helpful and turned it into a bash script. I added shell process backgrounding to make it run a bit faster for lots of USB devices connected to a system (which when this is most useful).

```bsh
#!/bin/bash                                                            
#findusbdev.sh
                                                           
if [[ "$1" =~ ^(-h|--help)$ ]]; then                                   
                                                                       
echo "Find which USB devices are associated with which /dev/ nodes     
Usage:                                                                 
  $0 [-h|--help] [searchString]                                        
                                                                       
  -h | --help   Prints this message                                    
  searchString  Print only /dev/<device> of matching output            
                With no arguments $0 prints information for all        
                possible USB device nodes                              
                                                                       
E.g. $0 \"FTDI_FT232\" - will show /dev/ttyUSBX for a device using     
the FTDI FT232 chipset.                                                
"                                                                      
    exit 0                                                             
fi                                                                     
                                                                       
devs=$( (                                                              
for sysdevpath in $(find /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/ -name dev ); do    
    # ( to launch a subshell here                                      
    (                                                                  
        syspath="${sysdevpath%/dev}"                                   
        devname="$(udevadm info -q name -p $syspath)"                  
        [[ "$devname" == "bus/"* ]] && exit                            
        eval "$(udevadm info -q property --export -p $syspath)"        
        [[ -z "$ID_SERIAL" ]] && exit                                  
        echo "/dev/$devname - $ID_SERIAL"                              
    )& # & here is causing all of these queries to run simultaneously  
done                                                                   
# wait then gives a chance for all of the iterations to complete       
wait                                                                   
# output order is random due to multiprocessing so sort results        
) | sort )                                                             
                                                                       
                                                                       
if [ -z "$1" ]; then                                                   
    echo "${devs}"                                                     
else                                                                   
    echo "${devs}" | grep "$1" | awk '{print $1}'                      
fi
```

Example usage:

```bsh
$ ./findusbdev.sh 
/dev/input/event15 - Peppercon_AG_Multidevice_E999EC989B0BAFB78F9F225288EC6B0A
/dev/input/event16 - Peppercon_AG_Multidevice_E999EC989B0BAFB78F9F225288EC6B0A
/dev/input/mouse0 - Peppercon_AG_Multidevice_E999EC989B0BAFB78F9F225288EC6B0A
/dev/ttyUSB0 - FTDI_FT230X_Basic_UART_D308B2AI
/dev/ttyUSB1 - FTDI_FT232R_USB_UART_AH07DPSR
```

```bsh
$ ./findusbdev.sh FT230X
/dev/ttyUSB0
```

```
$ ./findusbdev.sh -h
Find which USB devices are associated with which /dev/ nodes
Usage:
  ./findusbdev.sh [-h|--help] [searchString]

  -h | --help   Prints this message
  searchString  Print only /dev/<device> of matching output
                With no arguments ./findusbdev.sh prints information for all 
                possible USB device nodes

E.g. ./findusbdev.sh "FTDI_FT232" - will show /dev/ttyUSBX for a device using 
the FTDI FT232 chipset.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get all that info from sysfs, no need for `udevadm` or other programs which are not available on embedded linux systems.

```
vidpid_to_devs(){
        find $(grep -l "PRODUCT=$(printf "%x/%x" "0x${1%:*}" "0x${1#*:}")" \
                  /sys/bus/usb/devices/[0-9]*:*/uevent | sed 's,uevent$,,') \
           /dev/null -name dev -o -name dev_id |
        sed 's,[^/]*$,uevent,' |
        xargs sed -n -e s,DEVNAME=,/dev/,p -e s,INTERFACE=,,p
}

% vidpid_to_devs 067b:2303
/dev/ttyUSB0
% vidpid_to_devs 00da:8510
/dev/input/event6
/dev/input/event4
/dev/input/mouse1
/dev/input/event5
/dev/hidraw3
/dev/input/event7
/dev/hidraw4
```

The procedure is

a) look through `/sys/bus/usb/devices/*:*` for a device interface which matches your `vendor:product` tuple -- the `uevent` file in that directory contains a `PRODUCT=vendor/product/revision` (all in hex form without leading zeros).

b) look for any subdirectories which contain a `dev` file, then get the device name from the `DEVNAME=` entry from the `uevent` file in that subdirectory. Same with `dev_id` and `INTERFACE=` for network interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this below.

```
echo -n "/dev/"; dmesg | grep tty|grep USB|rev|awk '{print $1}'|rev
```

Comment: ow my eyes!   `dmesg | awk '/tty/ && /USB/ {print "/dev/"$1}'`  (The equivalent but clean...but still strange code; why not just ttyUSB together? and what was 2x rev for?)

Comment: The `rev` is used so the last field is accessed, this can be replaced by `$NF`: giving `dmesg | awk '/tty/ && /USB/ {print "/dev/"$NF}'`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you would like to know just the path to USB-serial adapter that connected last?

```
dmesg | awk '/tty/ && /USB/ {print "/dev/"$10}'|tail -1
```