# Running python script, error appears

Tags: linux, python

https://github.com/g-oikonomou/sensniff/blob/master/host/sensniff.py

The link above refers to a python script that is to be run on Ubuntu. When I run the script, the following error appears on the screen:

> Error opening port: /dev/ttyUSB0 The error was: ("could not open port
>   /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyUSB0'",)

**EDITION:**
I think that the script is supposed to translate data from FTDI to a Wireshark (pcap) format through so-called *PIPEs*. So probably it is searching for FTDI.

Comment: There is no `ttyUSB0` on your machine. It is the char device for usb-based serial ports. Today it is used mostly in usb-based mobilnet sticks.

Comment: You are debugging an usb wifi stick?

Answer (score 1):

your script using a device  `/dev/ttyUSB0` but that device is not attached to your system. so first you have to find attached device to your system and then run your script using

`python sensniff.py -d /dev/ttyUSB1`

or you can replace  `'device': '/dev/ttyUSB0'` in default section and run simply  `python sensniff.py` 
next your question may be how to know device name than you can refer this link to get device name [link to find device name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144029/command-to-determine-ports-of-a-device-like-dev-ttyusb0)