# Get the device path of USB given device ID

Tags: usb, peripherals

After plugging the USB to the port of my machine, if I do `lsusb` I see the device I am looking for:

`Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b573 Some Manufacturer`

If I list the devices under `/dev/`, I can see lots of device paths, such as `/dev/tty0`, `/dev/ttyUSB0`... etc. For what I understand, one of these paths will be my USB device, or be where my USB device is connected to.

How do I know which one is the one with the ID `04f2:b573`?

---

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144029/command-to-determine-ports-of-a-device-like-dev-ttyusb0) is similar to mine, however (referring to the [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144735/333961)) I don't know what exactly is `$ID_SERIAL`, or how to I set it to be equal to the Id I'm looking for, or even what is the correct path (since his example shows multiple device paths, such as `/dev/ttyACM0`, `/dev/sdb`, `/dev/input/event5` ...)

Also, the second answer assumes that I know the device is connected to `/dev/ttyUSB0`, which I don't know beforehand (testing it on this specific path gives me no device, by the way).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I know which one is the one with the ID `04f2:b573`?

There may be better ways to do it, but a quick and dirty way to do it is with:

```
find_by_id(){
    v=${1%:*}; p=${1#*:}  # split vid:pid into 2 vars
    v=${v#${v%%[!0]*}}; p=${p#${p%%[!0]*}}  # strip leading zeros
    grep -il "^PRODUCT=$v/$p" /sys/bus/usb/devices/*:*/uevent |
    sed s,uevent,, |
    xargs -r grep -r '^DEVNAME=' --include uevent
}
find_by_id 04f2:b573
```

My old Huawei phone appears as two serial ttys:

```
$ find_by_id 12d1:
/sys/bus/usb/devices/3-1:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0/uevent:DEVNAME=ttyUSB0
/sys/bus/usb/devices/3-1:1.1/ttyUSB1/tty/ttyUSB1/uevent:DEVNAME=ttyUSB1
```

You can change the last grep to

```
xargs -r egrep -rB2 '^DEVNAME=|^IFINDEX=' --include uevent
```

in order to also find the usb network interfaces:

```
$ find_by_id 0e8d:
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-6.2.3:1.0/net/usb0/uevent-INTERFACE=usb0
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-6.2.3:1.0/net/usb0/uevent:IFINDEX=10

$ find_by_id 03f0:
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-6.3:1.1/usbmisc/lp1/uevent-MAJOR=180
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-6.3:1.1/usbmisc/lp1/uevent-MINOR=1
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-6.3:1.1/usbmisc/lp1/uevent:DEVNAME=usb/lp1
```

Comment: I thought there would be an easier way but this worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @mosvy does not work on Debian systems because /sys/bus/usb/devices contains symlinks. It also will not work by following symlinks with `grep -R` because that filesystem contains symlink loops.

A simpler way to get what you need is:

`lsusb | grep NameOfYourDevice | sed -nr 's|Bus (.*) Device ([^:]*):.*|/dev/bus/usb/\1/\2|p'`

It converts the output of lsusb (from the usbutils package) to the /dev/bus/usb/... path

If you need a block/character device name, try something like this:

```
device() {
    v=${1%:*}; p=${1#*:}
    for dir in `find /sys/ -name idVendor | rev | cut -d/ -f 2- | rev`; do
        if grep -q $v $dir/idVendor; then
            if grep -q $p $dir/idProduct; then
                find $dir -name 'device' | rev | cut -d / -f 2 | rev
            fi
        fi
    done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it works on all *unix system. But in my computer, I can visit `/dev/bus/{BUSID}/{DEVICEID}`. The bus id and device id are what `lsusb` gives.

Comment: Thanks for info. I also find the device path under "/dev/bus/usb" but I couldn't read using "cat" command. Was you able to read? (ref: https://gpswebshop.com/blogs/tech-support-by-os-linux/how-to-connect-an-usb-gps-receiver-with-a-linux-computer)

Comment: @CloudCho I did not try to read it by `cat`. I need it to change it to 777 to let other users use it becuase when the default only allow root. I think whether you can use cat is determined by how the USB device works. The reference link you give use /dev/ttyACM0,. It is used for UART I guess.

Comment: does not work in Ubuntu 23.04